# static struct not working correctly

Tags: c, debugging, struct, linked-list

I am currently using a static struct that looks like the following:

```
typedef struct chunk_tag {
struct chunk_tag *next;
struct chunk_tag *prev;
int size;
} chunk_t;
chunk_t *morecore(int new_bytes);
```

It has size, next and prev.

Right under this I have the lines:

```
static chunk_t * First = NULL;
static chunk_t * Rover = NULL;
```

Then it goes into the function that looks like this:

```
void *Mem_alloc(int nbytes)
{
chunk_t *p = NULL;
//chunk_t *q = NULL;
chunk_t *best;
int blocks;
blocks = nbytes/sizeof(chunk_t);
if(nbytes % sizeof(chunk_t) != 0)
{
    blocks++;
}

if(First == NULL)//means new page
{
    First = morecore(PAGESIZE);
    if(First == NULL)
    {
        return p;
    }

    First->size = 0;
    Rover->size = PAGESIZE / sizeof(chunk_t)-1; //this line segfaults
    First->prev = (First + 1);
    First->next = (First + 1);
    Rover = First->next;
    Rover->prev = First;
    Rover->next = First; 
    requests++;
}
```

As you can see im trying to put something into the rover size. The line above puts zero into the First size. But when rover size is supposed to equal that little equation it segfaults. I know its not the equation because when I put it into first size it works correctly. Even if I try putting 0 into rover size it seg faults.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it crashes there, in the first call to `Mem_alloc` the variable `Rover` still points to `NULL` at that point.

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Oh if I put it below the Rover->prev and next line youre saying?

Comment: @user081608 Put that line after you *assign* to `Rover` (i.e. the `Rover = First->next;` line).

Answer (score 0):

Rover is declared as a pointer and is assigned to NULL.  This means it points to nothing.  So when you try to dereference it with Rover->size you're really trying to do this `(NULL).size`.   Which you can't do, hence the segmentation fault.

The code below will create an instance of chunk_t and assign the pointer Rover to it.

```
chunk_t newChunk;
Rover = newChunk;
```

Unfortunately, this way newChunk is declared locally inside Mem_alloc() and once you leave the method, say goodbye to newChunk.  If you want the instance to last after leaving the scope of the method you need to use `new`.

```
Rover = new chunk_t();
```

But don't forget to call a `delete` on Rover when you're done with it or you'll have a memory leak.

Or as mentioned in comments make sure you point Rover to a non-NULL First before dereferencing it.

Answer (score 0):

Rover is a pointer to `chunk_t` (struct). Rover can hold the address of instance of `chunk_t` (struct). Then, you may use Rover to get/set values of the object instance to which Rover points to.

Example:

```
chunk_t instance_one;
Rover = &instance_one;
.... //Assuming instance_one members are initialized. You may then access instance_one members using Rover
printf("size member of chunk_t: %d",Rover->size);
```

In your case, you are initializing Rover to NULL before `Mem_alloc()` is called

```
static chunk_t * Rover = NULL;
```

and dereferencing the NULL pointer in

```
Rover->size = PAGESIZE / sizeof(chunk_t)-1; //this line segfaults
```

You may have to create an object instance of chunk_t and make Rover point to that. Else, you have to do something similar to what you are doing for `First *`.